# getting a securityexception despite having granted permission

Tags: android, permissions, manifest, securityexception

I'm getting a java.lang.SecurityException for my app not having been granted android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS. even though I have added it into my manifests xml file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SoundActivity1"></activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Edit 1: Alright so I have this code that has to be run in a class outside of the activity, How would I go about asking for a users permission, then if they grant it, run this code, all in a class outside of the activity? -

```
Uri newRingtone = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.myapp/" + soundID); 
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,newRingtone);
```

And before anyone asks, yes, it needs to be outside of the activity with they way I set up my app

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler - `WRITE_SETTINGS` is not a permission you request via the runtime permissions model.

Answer (score 4):

Per the [`WRITE_SETTINGS` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SETTINGS):

> Note: If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission management screen. The app requests the user's approval by sending an intent with action [`ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS). The app can check whether it has this authorization by calling [`Settings.System.canWrite()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#canWrite(android.content.Context)).

Therefore you should use code such as:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
    !Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
  intent.setData("package:"+getPackageName());
  startActivityForResult(intent);
  // now wait for onActivityResult()
}
```